# What is the Dirac Delta distribution of functions with non-simple roots?

Tags: roots, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

While there is no trouble finding the formula for functions with distinct *simple* roots

$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{i:f(x_i)=0} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|} \tag{1}$$

e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function), I cannot find anything on functions with roots of higher multiplicity. Thus my question, how to treat that?

Comment: Simply use $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(f(x))\varphi(x)dx \overset{def}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1_{|f(x)| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}\varphi(x)dx $$ Note $\delta(f(x))$ is then well-defined as a distribution iff the limit exists and is continuous in $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, which is not the case when $f(x) \ne \mathcal{O}(x-a)$ at every $a, f(a) = 0$

Comment: @reuns Indeed, so for $f(x)$ with critical points $\delta(f(x))$ is not a "pure" distribution, but rather a "weak" or "critical" one which limits the test functions $\phi$ to those vanishing at the critical points of $f(x)$. And if [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2562503/163) is not horribly wrong it is actually sufficient that the $\phi$ have _simple_ roots at $f$'s critical points, and that's just a countable set... This is probably related to the problems of function inversion at critical points

Comment: If $f$ has only one zero at $0$ and $f'(0) = 0, f''(0) = 2C \ne 0$ then  $1_{|f(x)| < \epsilon} \approx 1_{|C x^2| < \epsilon}$ so that $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1_{|f(x)| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}\varphi(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{-(\epsilon/C)^{1/2}}^{(\epsilon/C)^{1/2}} \frac{1_{|f(x)| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}\varphi(x)dx = C^{-1/2} \lim_{x \to 0} \varphi(x) x^{-3/2}$$ (if the limit exists)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2481114/11127

Comment: @reuns I'm afraid I cannot entirely follow your derivation, could you please elaborate in an answer?

Comment: What do you not follow ? That $f$ has only one zero at $0$ where $f'(0) = 0, f''(0) = 2C$ means $f(x) = x^2 C + o(x^2)$ so that $1_{|f(x)| < \epsilon}\approx 1_{|x^2 C + o(x^2)| < \epsilon}\approx 1_{|x^2 C| < \epsilon} =1_{|x| < (\epsilon/C)^{1/2} } $ ?

Comment: @reuns OK, that clarifies the boundaries, but the last step is still too quick for me, sorry. According to [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2562503/163), your example should yield $$\delta\Big(x^2C+\mathcal O(x^3)\Big) = \frac{\delta(x)}{2\sqrt{Cx}},$$ is that consistent?

Comment: @reuns can you please provide a reference/citation for your definition of $\delta(f(x))$ in the first comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each root consider the local Taylor series, truncated to the first non-vanishing term:

Let $x_i$ denote the *distinct* roots of $f(x)$ with a multiplicity of $n_i$ respectively. Then

$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_i \delta\Bigg(\frac{f^{n_i)}(x_i)}{n_i!}(x-x_i)^{n_i} + \mathcal O\Big((x-x_i)^{n_i+1}\Big)\Bigg).$$

Since $\delta$ vanishes almost everywhere, the higher order terms can be dropped, and thus only $\delta(ax^n)$ needs to be determined. Change of variables yields

$$\begin{align*}
\delta(ax^n)\,dx &= \delta((\sqrt[n]ax)^n)\frac{d(\sqrt[n]ax)}{|\sqrt[n]a|}
\\ &= \delta((\sqrt[n]ax)^n)\frac{d(\sqrt[n]ax)^n}{|\sqrt[n]a\cdot n(\sqrt[n]ax)^{n-1}|} \qquad\Bigg|\quad ax^n \to x
\\ &= \delta(x)\frac{dx}{|n\sqrt[n]ax^{\frac{n-1}n}|}
\\ &= \frac{\delta(x)}{|n\sqrt[n]{ax^{n-1}}|}\,dx.
\end{align*}$$

Putting it all together we then get

$$\boxed{\delta(f(x)) = \sum_i\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{\Bigg|n_i\sqrt[n_i]{\frac{f^{(n_i)}(x_i)}{n_i!}(x-x_i)^{n_i-1}}\Bigg|}}$$

For $n_i=1$ this is consistent with $(1)$, for $n_i>1$ the singularity remains and apparently can only be cancelled when the $\delta$-distribution is applied to a function with a root of at least order $1-\frac1{n_i}$.

It might be interesting to consider $n_i\to\infty$, but it's getting late...

Comment: Note to self: Combine this with the [Weierstrass-Mittag-Leffler-Transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/987942/163) - sounds like fun...